# Регулярное выражение, которое выбирает все символы кроме первого

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка текста из различных символов. Нужно выбрать все символы кроме первого. Пример:

есть `abcdef,` нужно получить `bcdef`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если выбрать в группу захвата, то:

```
/^.(.*)/
```

Если просто получить совпадение из таких символов, то:

```
/(?!^).*/
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
let str = 'abcdef,';

// Может не надо регулярок?
console.info(str.substring(1)); // bcdef,

// Но если очень надо...
console.info(str.replace(/.(?=(.*))/, '')); // bcdef,
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
var text = 'bcdef';
var result = text.match(/^.(.*)$/);
console.log(result[1]);
```